# Preload function in sapper/svelte doesn't run

Tags: javascript, svelte, preload, sapper

I try to fetch an API in the prelaod function of my sapper project. However I can't get the preload function in sapper to run.

```html
<script context="module">

  export async function preload(page, session)
  {
    const res = await this.fetch(process.env.SAPPER_APP_API_URL + '/Paramedics');
    const paramedics = await res.json();

    console.log('SSR: ' + paramedics);

    return { paramedics };
  }
</script>

<script>
  import ParamedicCard from "./ParamedicCard.svelte";

  export let paramedics;

  console.log('CSR: ' + paramedics);
</script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-4">

  {#if paramedics}

    {#each paramedics as paramedic }

        <ParamedicCard {paramedic} />

    {/each}

  {:else}

    <p>loading...</p>
    
  {/if}

</div>
```

the console.log('SSR: ' + paramedics) doesn't run and the console.log('SSR: ' + paramedics) shows paramedics as undefined. I have red a lot on the web, and I tries even returning simple text values. from the preload function. But to no avail.

I'm using svelte 3.31 and sapper 0.28 with tailwindcss 2.0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it helps, remember that preload function only works in `routes`, not in components.
You can try to log and visit the url you're trying to fetch `console.log(process.env.SAPPER_APP_API_URL + '/Paramedics')` to see if everything is ok.

Comment: Hi Romain, Thanks, this is indeed the answer. Is was running this code from the component and not from the route. I have red a lot of documentation, but I can't remember reading this.

Comment: You can find more informations here : https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/blob/master/site/content/docs/04-preloading.md